# Delete children ,but delete parent record only where there no children.Sql Server 2008

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

Wondering if you could help me with a simple SQL query.

I have included a simple script to create the 2 tables and 01 SP. With some very small data. Any suggestions? Thanks

I have 2 tables

- Customer
- CustomerItem

The SQL query should:

1. Delete all the items from `CustomerItem` table based on `CustomerStoreID`.
2. Delete the customer as well BUT only when the customer has no children anymore

Script to create tables and some data:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Customer]') AND type in (N'U'))
   DROP TABLE [dbo].[Customer]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer]
   ([CustomerID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Surname] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CustomerID] ASC)
   ) ON [PRIMARY]

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[CustomerItem]') AND type in (N'U'))
   DROP TABLE [dbo].[CustomerItem]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerItem]
   ([CustomerItemID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CustomerStoreID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CustomerItemDescription] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_CustomerItem] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([CustomerItemID] ASC)
   ) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Customer]([CustomerID], [Name], [Surname])
   SELECT 1, N'John ', N'Smith' UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, N'Mark', N'Bloggs' UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, N'Richard', N'Lay'

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CustomerItem]([CustomerItemID], [CustomerID], [CustomerStoreID], [CustomerItemDescription])
   SELECT 1, 1, 1, N'BookOne' UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, 1, 1, N'BookTwo' UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, 1, 2, N'BookThree'UNION ALL
   SELECT 4, 1, 2, N'BookFour' UNION ALL
   SELECT 5, 2, 2, N'BookFive'UNION ALL
   SELECT 6, 2, 2, N'BookSix' UNION ALL
   SELECT 7, 3, 3, N'BookSeven' UNION ALL
   SELECT 8, 3, 3, N'BookEight'
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DBO.SYSOBJECTS WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[DeleteCustomerAndItemsByStoreId]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
   DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteCustomerAndItemsByStoreId]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteCustomerAndItemsByStoreId
                   @CustomerStoreID INT
/*
   Delete all customerItems  based on @CustomerStoreID
   Delete the customer itself when he not longer has customerItems
*/
AS
   DELETE FROM CustomerItem 
   WHERE CustomerStoreID = @CustomerStoreID

   ---Loop through the customer table and  Delete Customer if no longer has children
   --???
   COMMIT
```

Basically when processing/deleting the last `customerItem` also delete the customer.

Stored procedure will only have one parameter `@CustomerStoreID`

Comment: As a side-note: if find those checks you do overly complicated..... for a table, try this instead: `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'Customer')` and for a procedure use the `sys.procedures` catalog view - much easier to use than the generic `sys.objects` and then having to specify what types of objects you're looking for, I think....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delete from Customer where CustomerID in
(select distinct CustomerID 
 from customer c left outer join CustomerItem i 
  on c.CustomerID = i.CustomerID
 where i.CustomerID is null)
```

Comment: Thanks That worked!! Thanks to everybody for their input and time.Sorry if not clear

Comment: @Beth, I can't edit your answer because my edit is only one character .. 
but you should write (select distinct c.CustomerID
Otherwise you might get the error "Ambiguous column name"

Answer (score 2):

```
delete c
from [Customer] as c
    left join [CustomerItem] as ci
    on ci.[CustomerID] = c.[CustomerID]
where ci.[CustomerID] is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
delete Customer 
where not exists (select 1 
                  from CustomerItem 
         where  Customer.CustomerID = CustomerItem.CustomerID)
```

Comment: I was assuming he means delete those customers affected by the first deletion (in `CustomerItems`) - not all of them (but for all of them, your code certainly works just fine!)

Comment: He needs a `REVERSE CASCADE DELETE`  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Basically your stored proc should look something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteCustomerAndItemsByStoreId
                    @CustomerStoreID INT
AS
   DECLARE @CustomerIDs TABLE(CustomerID INT)

   -- do the first delete and output the deleted CustomerID's into a table variable
   DELETE CustomerItem 
   OUTPUT DELETED.CustomerID INTO @CustomerIDs(CustomerID)
   WHERE CustomerStoreID = @CustomerStoreID

   -- delete from the Customer table when no CustomerItems exist anymore for that CustomerID
   DELETE dbo.Customer
   OUTPUT DELETED.CustomerID 
   FROM @CustomerIDs c
   WHERE
      dbo.Customer.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
      AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.CustomerItem WHERE CustomerID = c.CustomerID)
```

That should do the two-step delete - first delete all `CustomerItem` rows for the `CustomerStoreID` defined, and then delete those customers from that set of customers affected by the first delete that don't have any more `CustomerItem` entries.

**Update:** when I run this:

```
SELECT * FROM customer

EXEC DeleteCustomerAndItemsByStoreId @CustomerStoreID = 2

SELECT * FROM customer
```

I get:

```
CustomerID  Name       Surname
   1        John        Smith
   2        Mark        Bloggs
   3        Richard     Lay

CustomerID     -- that from the "OUTPUT Deleted.CustomerID"
    2

CustomerID  Name       Surname
   1        John        Smith
   3        Richard     Lay
```

Customer no. 2 is gone - that's with your script, your data

Comment: Yes customerstoreID 1, has 2 customers..that is why I created my answer like I did

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply and time. I have tried your query but does not seem to work if I execute  EXEC [dbo].[DeleteCustomerAndItemsByStoreId] @CustomerStoreID = 2 . I still see the customer with a customerID=2 in the table as it should dissappear.Basically i need to delete all the customerItems that belong to a customerID and when the customerID has no more children delete that too.