# ORA-02292: integrity constraint violated - child record found while creating procedures in ORACLE SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, constraints, ora-02292

I have written a procedure that has as input the CUSTOMER_ID. Then the procedure deletes the corresponding customer from the table CUSTOMERS.

```
CREATE OR REPlACE PROCEDURE DELETE_CUSTOMER 
(CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER) AS 
TOT_CUSTOMERS NUMBER;
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM CUSTOMERS
    WHERE CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID = DELETE_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID;
    TOT_CUSTOMERS := TOT_CUSTOMERS - 1;
    END;
/
```

I have to execute the procedure to delete customer with id 1.

```
EXECUTE DELETE_CUSTOMER(01);
```

When I do this, I get an error

```
Error starting at line : 120 in command -
BEGIN DELETE_CUSTOMER(01); END;
Error report -
ORA-02292: integrity constraint (TUG81959.ORDERS_FK_CUSTOMERS) violated - child record found
ORA-06512: at "TUG81959.DELETE_CUSTOMER", line 5
ORA-06512: at line 1
02292. 00000 - "integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - child record found"
*Cause:    attempted to delete a parent key value that had a foreign
           dependency.
*Action:   delete dependencies first then parent or disable constraint.
```

I know this is because there is a foreign key for CUSTOMER_ID on the table ORDERS, which means the customer cannot be deleted because he has placed an order. 
**How do I write the code so that I can first delete the corresponding ORDER_DETAILS and then delete the corresponding ORDERS so that I can finally be able to delete a record from CUSTOMERS?**

I tried rewriting the code but I am just lost now:

```
CREATE OR REPlACE PROCEDURE DELETE_CUSTOMER 
(CUSTOMER_ID_IN NUMBER) AS 
TOT_CUSTOMERS NUMBER;
CURSOR C1 IS
DELETE FROM ORDERS
WHERE ORDERS.ORDER_ID = CUSTOMER_ID.ORDER_ID;
CURSOR C2 IS
DELETE FROM ORDER_DETAILS
WHERE ORDER_DETAILS.ORDER_ID = CUSTOMER_ID.ORDER_ID;
CURSOR C3 IS
DELETE FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID = DELETE_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID;
BEGIN
    OPEN C1;
    OPEN C2;
    OPEN C3;
    IF C1%FOUND AND C2%FOUND AND C3%FOUND
    THEN TOT_CUSTOMERS := TOT_CUSTOMERS - 1;
    END IF;
    CLOSE C1;
    CLOSE C2;
    CLOSE C3;
END;
/
```

Here are the tables for reference:
[image]

Comment: Another way is to set constraint as defered. [On Deferring and Bulking Up](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-may/o31asktom-354139.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*There are two ways to accomplish this :*

> You may use cascade on delete ( *drop&create again* ) :

---

```
   drop constraint order_details_fk_orders; 

   alter table order_details add constraint order_details_fk_orders 
   foreign key(order_id) references orders(order_id)  
   on delete cascade;

   delete orders where customer_id = &i_cust_id;
```

**or**

> You may delete your detail records first :

---

with following procedure :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PR_DELETE_CUSTOMER(
                                                I_CUSTOMER_ID       orders.customer_id%type, 
                                                O_TOT_CUSTOMERS out number
                                              ) IS 
BEGIN
   delete order_details where order_id in ( select order_id from orders where customer_id = I_CUSTOMER_ID );
   delete orders where customer_id = I_CUSTOMER_ID;
   delete customers where customer_id = I_CUSTOMER_ID;
   select count(1) into O_TOT_CUSTOMERS from orders; 
END;
```

and then

```
 var v_tot_customers number;  
 execute pr_delete_customer(1,:v_tot_customers);  
 print v_tot_customers;
```

Comment: I have to use the second way unfortunately, but I have no idea how to implement it into the procedure code. I have updated my code above but now I'm completely lost.

Comment: like so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382906/delete-children-but-delete-parent-record-only-where-there-no-children-sql-serve

Comment: @pyuntae i've added procedure.

Comment: I get another error `Error(62,31): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "ORD_DET_CUST_ID": invalid identifier`

Comment: I changed `"ORD_DET_CUST_ID"` to `order_id` and it compiled but when I try to execute the procedure `EXECUTE DELETE_CUSTOMER(01);` I get an error message saying `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DELETE_CUSTOMER'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 52:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.`

Comment: @pyuntae of course you may get an error. It stands for your `order_details's customer id column` which i don't know how called in your table.

Comment: the names are listed on the tables in the image that I have posted. `order_detail does not have customer_id but has order_id which is linked to orders table that has both order_id and customer_id.`

Comment: pay attention that there are two parameters. call `DELETE_CUSTOMER(1,v_tot_customers)` v_tot_customers as an out parameter, i think you need this.

Comment: What do you mean, like `EXECUTE DELETE_CUSTOMER(01,V_TOT_CUSTOMERS);`?

Comment: i've edited again for the first delete, by the way V_TOT_CUSTOMERS is just a parameter you may define and use as an out argument of your procedure, if you want you may get rid of it, but i think you need the number of customers.

Comment: Now there's another compiler log error `Error(67,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with    <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157212/discussion-between-barbaros-ozhan-and-pyuntae).

Answer (score 0):

Delete the referential child record first before deleting the parent record.

```
delete from child_table where parent_id='FCS000154'; 
delete from parent_table where parent_id='FCS000154'; 

COMMIT;
```

This is a simple way to do this.